# wait until all the child processes are finished in NodeJS when using fork

Tags: node.js, fork

I have a nodeJS script where it goes through a list of URLs to download pdfs. Each Url contains 5 pdfs. So I used fork to download all 5 pdfs at once. What I need to do is to move to next URL only and only after all child processes (downloads) finished executing.

this is my main.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const fork = require('child_process').fork;
const ls = fork("download.js");

var list = [];
var links = [];
var names = [];
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(({headless: false}));
    const page = await browser.newPage();
/*  
    const list_arr = fs.readFileSync('link_list.csv').toString().split(",");
    
    for(l = 1; l < list_arr.length; l+2){
        links[(l - 1) / 2] = list_arr[l];
        names([l - 1] / 2) = list_arr[l - 1];
    }
    
    for(let i = 0; i < links.length; i++){*/
    //  url = links[i];
    //  name = names[i];
    url = 'https://www.responsibilityreports.com/Company/abb-ltd';
    name = 'abcd';
        
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        
        await page.waitForXPath('//li[@class="top_content_list"]/div[@class="left"]/span[@class="ticker_name"]');
        let ticker_r = await page.$x('//li[@class="top_content_list"]/div[@class="left"]/span[@class="ticker_name"]');
        let ticker =  await (await ticker_r[0].getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
        let cat = ticker[0].toLowerCase();
        //console.log(ticker);  

        await page.waitForXPath('//li[@class="top_content_list"]/div[@class="right"]');
        let exchange_r = await page.$x('//li[@class="top_content_list"]/div[@class="right"]');
        let exchange = (await (await exchange_r[0].getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue()).split('Exchange').pop().split('More').shift().replace(/\n/gm, '').trim();
        //console.log(exchange);    

        await page.waitForXPath('//div[@class="most_recent_content_block"]/span[@class="bold_txt"]');
        let mr_res = await page.$x('//div[@class="most_recent_content_block"]/span[@class="bold_txt"]');
        let mr_txt = await mr_res[0].getProperty('textContent');
        let mr_text = await mr_txt.jsonValue();
        console.log(mr_text);
        
        let [mr_year, ...mr_rest] = mr_text.split(' ');
        let mr_type = mr_rest.join(' ').trim();
        
        mr_url = 'https://www.responsibilityreports.com/HostedData/ResponsibilityReports/PDF/'+ exchange + '_' + ticker + '_' + mr_year + '.pdf';
        
        let mr_obj = {
            "year" : mr_year,
            "type" : mr_type.trim(),
            "url" : mr_url
        }
        
        list.push(mr_obj);
        
        await page.waitForXPath('//div[@class="archived_report_content_block"]/ul/li/div/span[@class="heading"]');
        let ar_reps = await page.$x('//div[@class="archived_report_content_block"]/ul/li/div/span[@class="heading"]');
        console.log(ar_reps.length);
        for(let k = 0; k < ar_reps.length; k++){
            let ar_txt = await ar_reps[k].getProperty('textContent');
            let ar_text = await ar_txt.jsonValue();
            
            let [ar_year, ...ar_rest] = ar_text.split(' ');
            
            if(parseInt(ar_year) < 2017){
                break;
            }
            
            let ar_type = ar_rest.join(' ');
            ar_url = 'https://www.responsibilityreports.com/HostedData/ResponsibilityReportArchive/' + cat + '/'+ exchange + '_' + ticker + '_' + ar_year + '.pdf';
            
            let ar_obj = {
                "year" : ar_year,
                "type" : ar_type,
                "url" : ar_url
            }
            
            list.push(ar_obj);
            
            console.log(ar_year);
        }
    /*}*/
    
    for(f = 0; f < list.length; f++){
        let url_s = list[f].url;
        let type_s = list[f].type;
        let year_s = list[f].year;
        ls.on('exit', (code)=>{
            console.log('child_process exited with code ${code}');
        });
        ls.on('message', (msg) => {
            ls.send([url_s ,name,type_s,year_s]);
            console.log(msg);
        });
    }
    await browser.close();
    console.log('done');
})();
```

and child.js

```
const down_path = 'downloads/';
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
 
process.on('message', async (arr)=> {
    console.log("CHILD: url received from parent process", arr);
    url = arr[0];
    name = arr[1];
    type = arr[2];
    year = arr[3];
    await download(url,name,type,year);
});

process.send('Executed');

async function download(url,name,type,year) {
    https.get(url, res => {
        const stream = fs.createWriteStream(down_path + name + '_' + type + '_' + year + '.pdf');
        res.pipe(stream);
        stream.on('finish', async() => {
            console.log('done : ' + year);
            stream.close();
        });
    });
}
```

is there anyway I can modify my code so that it'll only go ahead once the child processes finish executing?

**EDIT:** I also found that child.js are not exiting after stream.close();